# How can I deploy a Java-Spring Maven Application on Tomcat v8.0 (Restful WebService)

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, tomcat8

I am unable to deploy the Spring-Maven Restful WebService on Tomcat v8.0. My OS is windows 7. When I deploy it through Tomcat App Manager then I get a screen with the link "Click To Enter", although I have not created any links like that. Please see the image below.

Thanks,

[image]

Comment: Did you create the project from an archetype with `mvn archetype:generate`? It looks like the default page of a Spring archetype. And, by the way, it looks like you actually managed to deploy the webapp...

Comment: @EvilToad Ahan Thanks for your help. I have created this project using "Spring Project" and I think these 'mvn archetype:generate' are in the Meven Project. Moreover, the task I want to achieve is in this tutorial [link](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/). I want to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly how it is supposed to work. When you create a new "Simple Spring Web Maven" project in Eclipse (I guess this is what you did), the wizard creates a working Maven project that can be immediately built with Maven. The created WAR can be, in turn, deployed to Tomcat (i.e. copy the WAR file to the webapp folder of Tomcat) or whatever container you are using.

As I said in the comment, it looks like you actually managed to deploy the WAR and what you are seeing is the default home page corresponding to the "index.jsp" file, that is created by the wizard.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand :)